# Create New GUID in repository instead of in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, guid

I am creating a new MVC solution using the instruction of an udemy video.  The instructor uses the repository pattern to interact with the models but he uses an int.  I am, on the other hand, using a Guid, which he does not show.  I know that while an int is created automatically, I need to explicitly create the Guid as I do here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCarrier(Carrier carrier)
{
      carrier.CarrierID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
      carriers.Insert(carrier);
      carriers.Commit();

      return RedirectToAction("CarrierList");
}
```

However, since I have numerous classes I think this would be a lot of extra code.  Shouldn't I create the Guid for the entity id right before I insert it?  I just cannot figure out how to do it in the repository.  Here is the repository code:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DataContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
         dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

and here is the interface:

```
namespace WarehouseScheduling.DAL.Contracts
{
    public interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        void Commit();
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        void Delete(object id);
        void Dispose();
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(object filter);
        TEntity GetById(object id);
        TEntity GetFullObject(object id);
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetPaged(int top = 20, int skip = 0, object orderBy = null, object filter = null);
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I know that while an int is created automatically` not at all. At some point every piece of data gets generated, either by client code or by the DB itself. An `int` has nothing inherent to it to "autogenerate". Moving the `guid` generation to the DB via a default constraint will give the very same result.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can enforce the generic type TEntity to be an interface that allow getting and setting Guid

```
public interface IHasGuid
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can put restriction on your repository class/interface so that it only works with entities of type IHasGuid

```
namespace WarehouseScheduling.DAL.Contracts
{
    public interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : IHasGuid
    {
        void Commit();
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        void Delete(object id);
        void Dispose();
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(object filter);
        TEntity GetById(object id);
        TEntity GetFullObject(object id);
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetPaged(int top = 20, int skip = 0, object orderBy = null, object filter = null);
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

and also modify the implementation similarly but add code to automatically add in the Guid

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : IHasGuid
{
    internal DataContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
         entity.Id = new Guid();
         dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Remember that your entity (Carrier in this case) has to implement IHasGuid

```
public class Carrier : IHasGuid
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // other fields below
}
```

Comment: Where would I put the interface?  In the RepositoryBase Class? or a separate class?

Comment: @djblois should be in a separate file ```IHasGuid.cs``` or something.

Comment: @djblois and remember that your class ```Carrier``` has to implement ```IHasGuid```

Comment: goaty, sorry I added more information to the original question.  I did not realize, since I am new to interfaces, that my repository base already inherets an interface.  How do I do it with the code above?